# No Data appearing in Redshift from MongoDB using AWS DMS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am trying to test the AWS data migration service to fetch some data from Atlas MongoDB to Redshift cluster, I have created the replication instance, both the endpoints, successfully tested the connection them and created the replication task, the task loads and completes normally but no data appears in redshift, just empty tables?

Anybody can you please help what might be the reason?

[image: Load complete but no rows in table statistics]

Comment: I am just loading the standard sample dataset from MongoDB to Redshift

Comment: I was finally able to fix all issues for this , please tag me if its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first try to debug it , modify the task and enable cloudwatch logs and run the task again and look at the logs , also enalbe data assessment task you will need to add an iam role for that. Some mistakes I made was that the endpoint for mongodb needs an atlasadmin login , no other will work , tell me if it did not work. Also make sure  all tasks have correct db name , capitol letters matter , same happend with me , my endpoint had db name with small letters and my task had db name with capitol letter , the task was successful but no data.Lastly and most important is that make sure your mongo peering connection is correctly figured with aws. Im sure when you see the logs there will be an un authorized error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the detail you mention, it seems like a case that happened to me, it is very strange because indeed if you review the logs or statistics of the task you will probably not see any clues, but in summary, I reviewed the details of the task and the **endpoint**.

In the latter I found something where I had doubts, the configuration of the database name, so I assumed that was why since it said **"admin"**, it turns out that it was later changed and that was it, the following [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MongoDB.html#CHAP_Source.MongoDB.Configuration) also said it, that will be my support on this occasion, greetings